# Azure Active Directory - MVC application best practices to store the access token

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I've set up a simple MVC Application using Azure Active Directory(AAD).

I need to query the AAD Graph API in order to manage application roles and groups from my application.

In the `Startup` class, I received the AccessToken like that:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier;

    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
        new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = Constants.ClientId,
            Authority = Constants.Authority,
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = Constants.PostLogoutRedirectUri,
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
            {
                // If there is a code in the OpenID Connect response, redeem it for an access token and refresh token, and store those away.
                AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) =>
                {
                    var code = context.Code;
                    var credential = new ClientCredential(Constants.ClientId, Constants.ClientSecret);
                    var signedInUserId =
                        context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
                    var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Constants.Authority,
                        new TokenDbCache(signedInUserId));
                    var result = authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(
                        code, new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)), credential,
                        Constants.GraphUrl);

                    var accessToken = result.AccessToken;                        
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            }
        });
}
```

To instantiate the `ActiveDirectoryClient` class, I need to pass the AccessToken :

```
var servicePointUri = new Uri("https://graph.windows.net");
var serviceRoot = new Uri(servicePointUri, tenantID);
var activeDirectoryClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(serviceRoot,
        async () => await GetTokenForApplication());
```

I am wondering if storing the AccessToken as a claim is a good solution (line to add in the `Startup` class)?

```
context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaim(new 
    Claim("OpenId_AccessToken", result.AccessToken));
```

**EDIT Token is already stored..**

Get it !!! Thank you George.
So my Token has been stored in the database using the `TokenDbCache` class.

To get it again (in one of my controller) according to the sample:

```
public async Task<string> GetTokenForApplication()
{
    string signedInUserID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
    string tenantID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid").Value;
    string userObjectID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;

    // get a token for the Graph without triggering any user interaction (from the cache, via multi-resource refresh token, etc)
    ClientCredential clientcred = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
    // initialize AuthenticationContext with the token cache of the currently signed in user, as kept in the app's database
    AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(aadInstance + tenantID, new TokenDbCache<ApplicationDbContext>(signedInUserID));
    AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(graphResourceID, clientcred, new UserIdentifier(userObjectID, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));
    return authenticationResult.AccessToken;
}
```

What I don't know from the `AuthenticationContext`:
If the token has already been requested, it is going to retrieve it from the `TokenDbCache`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are retrieving tokens through Adal it is caching it in NaiveCache object.

Code to retrieve token withing StartUp class:

```
  AuthenticationResult kdAPiresult = authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(code, new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)), credential, "Your API Resource ID");
                            string kdAccessToken = kdAPiresult.AccessToken;
```

In Azure Active Directory samples (https://github.com/AzureADSamples) this object utilized to retrieve token within app controllers. Youcan implement your own caching to retrieve it in a same manner.

In your controller code you can do following:

```
IOwinContext owinContext = HttpContext.GetOwinContext();
                string userObjectID = owinContext.Authentication.User.Claims.First(c => c.Type == Configuration.ClaimsObjectidentifier).Value;
                NaiveSessionCache cache = new NaiveSessionCache(userObjectID);
                AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Configuration.Authority, cache);
                TokenCacheItem kdAPITokenCache = authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().Where(c => c.Resource == "You API Resource ID").FirstOrDefault();
```

You can store token in claims as well if your are obtaining tokens not though AuthenticationContext (3d party apis)

Comment: I saw the sample but I am wondering why I need to instantiate a new AuthenticationContext ? Also there is an AcquireTokenSilentAsync method in the AuthenticationContext class. Is it going to send a new http request to the AAD Graph API or it is going to try get the value from the TokenCacheItem ?

Comment: When you calling AcquireTokenSilentAsync it is trying to send refresh token request if  Context has been constructed with cache. See implementation in https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/blob/master/src/ADAL.Common/AcquireTokenHandlerBase.cs