# Azure - AD - AcquireTokenSilent giving error failed_to_acquire_token_silently

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, adal

We are using Azure AD to authenticate and get the refreshed access token every 30 mins. We invoke below method which acquires security token and add it to request header.

```
var userObjectId = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;
var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority, new NaiveSessionCache(userObjectId));
var credential = new ClientCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"],
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientSecret"]);

    try
    {
    var authenticationResult = authContext.AcquireTokenSilent(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebAPIBaseAddress"], credential, new UserIdentifier(userObjectId, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));
    //set cookie for azure oauth refresh token - on successful login
    var httpCookie = HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["RefreshToken"];
    if (httpCookie != null)
        httpCookie.Value = authenticationResult.RefreshToken;

    request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authenticationResult.AccessToken);
    }
    catch
    {
    //Get access token using Refresh Token 
    var authenticationResult = authContext.AcquireTokenByRefreshToken(httpCookie.Value, credential, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebAPIBaseAddress"]);
    }
```

In above method, we have used AcquireTokenSilent method which gives us access token. Since access token lasts only for certain period of time.
After its expiry, we call AcquireTokenByRefreshToken to get refresh token.

The above code works well, however we are getting below exception randomly:

```
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalSilentTokenAcquisitionException: Failed to acquire token silently. Call method AcquireToken 
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AcquireTokenSilentHandler.SendTokenRequestAsync() 
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AcquireTokenHandlerBase.<RunAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
ErrorCode: failed_to_acquire_token_silently
```

What could be the reason of such inconsistent behaviour? The same code is working on few environments (Stage/Dev) but its throwing error randomly on Production.

Please suggest.

Comment: How did you configure the authentication ? Did you have a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34888661/azure-active-directory-mvc-application-best-practices-to-store-the-access-toke ?

Comment: What is the version are you using for Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory?

Comment: @Thomas: Thanks. We have done the authentication in preetymuch the same fashion in startup.cs as mentioned in the link shared by you.

Comment: @juvchan: The specific version of Microsoft.IdentityModel.clients.ActiveDirectory we are using is 2.16 (2.16.20422.1202)

Comment: Is there any specific reason to stick with this old version? I recommend you to upgrade to the latest stable version (2.20.301151232) which just released less than 1 week ago. Works fine for me. I believe it also does not contain breaking change which break your code. Avoid using alpha release.

Comment: Thanks @juvchan. But, how is it working with other environments for which the AD is configured under the same subscription with the same code base?

Comment: @SushantSonarghare, when you mention "inconsistent", do you mean the error only occurs in your Production environment and only occurs randomly?

Comment: Yes @juvchan. This is happening only on Production and that too randomly.

Comment: Based on experience, this could due to configurations because the same codebase works fine on other environments... There is too little info to help you determine the root cause at this point

Comment: @SushantSonarghare, when you try to get the token silently, it will get the token from the TokenCache. So if the token is not valid anymore you will get this error. what you can do is catching AdalException and force the user to reauthentificate.

Comment: Side note, you should never need to call AcquireTokenByRefreshToken. If you call AcquireTokenSilent, ADAL will automatically select the best refresh token from the cache - and it will save the new refresh token transparently. Let me stress this: assuming that you are persisting your cache, there should be no scenario whatsoever in which you must manipulate the refresh token directly.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your responses. Unfortunately, we are getting the exception in other environments too.

Comment: Try enabling logging to get better diagnostics. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/27364887/18044

Comment: As a side / side note, adding RefreshToken as a cookie, provides the user-agent the opportunity to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We were able to resolve this. It seems to be a small mistake in the code itself.
When the AccessToken expires, it throws an exception and it tries to fetch a new one using AcquireTokenByRefreshToken in the catch block. Here we were not setting the newly received refresh token back in the Cookie.
We need to add below statement in the catch block also, so that it would get the Refresh token, which can then be passed back to generate a new Access Token.

```
httpCookie.Value = authenticationResult.RefreshToken;
```

Comment: It's not how OAuth should be used! Storing any token in cookies is highly insecure (refer to http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/100600/where-to-store-access-and-refresh-tokens-on-asp-net-client-web-app-calling-a-r ). Besides it will lead you to strange auth flows.

Please read again answer here or my other answer ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25267831/asp-net-web-api-and-openid-connect-how-to-get-access-token-from-authorization-c/34730754#34730754 ) to see how to handle refresh tokens. Basically saying they should be transparent for you (acquire silent does it automatically).

Comment: you cannot do this in catch method. Here the issue is authenticationResult is not picking data and throws error at that point. how can authenticationResult.RefreshToken has value?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, before using `AcquireTokenSilent` you must invoke `AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync`.

```
var context = new AuthenticationContext(authorityUri);
var credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecretKey);

await context.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(authorizationCode, new Uri(redirectUri), credential);
```

`AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync` stores access token and refresh token in `TokenCache.DefaultShared` (for user uniqueId received from auth procedure).

Assuming you do that, access tokens and refresh tokens do expire. If that happens, you must catch `AdalSilentTokenAcquisitionException` exception:

```
try
{
    // currentUser = new UserIdentifier() for: ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier")
    AuthenticationResult authResult = await context.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(resourceUri, credential, currentUser);

    return authResult.AccessToken;
}
catch (AdalSilentTokenAcquisitionException)
{
    return null;
}
```

Invoke this method before every request to the resource. It doesn't cost much, ideally nothing, or oauth API hit with refreshToken.

But when `AdalSilentTokenAcquisitionException` is thrown (or it's a first call). You must call procedure that performs full access code retrieval from oauth API. What procedure? It depends on the type of auth process you're using.

With full owin auth it can be:

- redirect to authority uri with `{"response_type", "code" }`
- or invoking `HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);` (return null from controller's action as the `Challenge()` method alters HTTP response to force redirection to auth server). End processing of current request (with returning null). Auth server will invoke your authorization method (AuthorizationCodeReceived event from UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication's Notifications) with new authorization code. Later, redirect back to the origin page that needs the token.

So, you may get AdalSilentTokenAcquisitionException because cache is expired and refreshToken is expired. You have to reauthenticate again (it's transparent, no login page required).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer & sorry for the late reply, but we are doing the steps suggested by you. Can you please elaborate more on the Full Code retrieval section of your answer?  var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority, new NaiveSessionCache(userObjectId));
            authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(code,
             new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)), credential, GraphResourceId);

Comment: @SushantSonarghare - What kind of authentication process are you using? a) Owin .net library like here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-multitenant-openidconnect/blob/master/TodoListWebApp/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs#L34 ; or b) ADAL library https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-developer-authenticate-to-power-bi-service/  ?